# the Location E:\ is currently Unavailable

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, dvd

Earlier today I was copying files off a DVD, everything working fine. Then I tried copying something off another DVD and I got an error message saying the location E:\ is currently unavailable. So later on I tried copying something off a DVD which I knew works, and now E: is not even showing up under This PC.

I am running Windows 10, (updated from Windows 8.1), on a laptop that is less than a year old. When I put a DVD in the disk drive, it whirs into life, so I am certain it still works. I have checked in Device Manager and nothing is showing up as not functioning correctly. I would also like to avoid having to pull the laptop apart.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the PC (without a DVD in the DVD drive) and then inserting the DVD?

Comment: Actually I have done a scan of the computer and the DVD drive is not listed under the disk drives

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. "**Have you tried restarting the PC**"?

Comment: no I have not yet restarted it

Comment: Then please try that. It is the first thing to try in any troubleshooting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did the tried and tested restart and everything with regards to the disk drive is working correctly. So I am at a loss as to what went wrong... But that's Windows for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but currently I can't comment.

Have you tried showing empty drives as shown in http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6969-drives-hide-show-empty-drives-computer-folder.html?

**Edit:** If this doesn't help, I've two more ideas you can try:

1. Odler Windows' can shut down the CD/DVD drive to save energy. This is controlled in energy settings. To check if this is causing the problem, it should be enough to run the laptop with its power supply attached.
2. Have a look into disk management (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/f/open-disk-management.htm) and check if your CD/DVD drive appears there.

Comment: Tried that still not showing up